# python argument unpacking puzzling behaviour

Tags: python, argument-passing, argument-unpacking

I have a problem understanding the process of argument unpacking from a list using the star operator in python.

I have followed the [documentation entry](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and tried to re-create my own little example.

So I've defined a simple list of numbers:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
```

and made a quick check, this works:

```
print(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

and this (just for heads-up):

```
print([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

On the other hand this bit **fails**:

```
print(*[1, 2, 3])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(*[1, 2, 3])
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And this also fails:

```
print(*list)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(*list)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I made sure everything in the documentation works:

```
list = [1, 2]
range(*list)
[1]
```

And it did.

I'd like to understand how exactly argument unpacking from list works and what to expect from it, because it doesn't seem as straightforward as I thought.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7? In which case, the `print` statement is not a function, so the star operator won't work with it the way you expect.

Comment: Works on python3.2!

You want to answer so I'll accept your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpacking only works when you are inside a function call:

```
>>> def foo(a,b,c):
...     pass
...
>>> foo(*[1,2,3])
>>>
```

Using it elsewhere will cause an Error:

```
>>> (*[1,2,3])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    (*[1,2,3])
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In Python 2.7, `print` is not a function, it is a statement. As far as the interpreter is concerned, this:

```
print(*[1,2,3])
```

Is syntactically equivalent to this:

```
print *[1,2,3]
```

Which is invalid. In Python 3.X, `print` is now a function, so unpacking will work.

```
>>> print(*[1,2,3])
1 2 3
```

You can port the functional `print` back to 2.7 by importing from the future:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(*[1,2,3])
1 2 3
```

Comment: i think `print *[1,2,3]` is not valid

Comment: @FooBarUser, I agree. That's why I wrote "...Which is invalid"

Answer (score 0):

change: `print(\*[1, 2, 3])` to: `print(*[1, 2, 3])`

```
>>> print(*[1,2,3])
1 2 3

>>> print(\*[1,2,3])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(\*[1,2,3])
                   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

it wont work for python2 print because its not a function. it will work for python 3. example:

```
>>> def x(a,b,c):
...     print(a,b,c)

>>> x(*[1,2,3])
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: sorry, that's a typo in my post, I will fix it immediately

Comment: doesn't work for me... I added it here because of the formatting that takes place on the site :)

Comment: it will work when you pass it to a function, on python2 print is not a function